# Run spark application in Junit

Tags: java, apache-spark, junit, spark-submit

I have a java application which uses Apache Spark. I run it using spark-submit.

The format of the command I use is:

```
bin/spark-submit \  
--master spark://sparkmaster:7077 \  
--class com.ic.spark.sto.test.Runner \ 
/spark-test/target/spark-test-2.0.jar \   
/spark-test/resources/smallfile.csv \ 
/spark-test/resources/config.properties \ 
true false false
```

I want to run this as a JUnit. I've created a test class and copied the contents of the main method(from com.ic.spark.sto.test.Runner) method into a test there. When I run it I get an error that suggests the core-site.xml can't be found. At the minute I am trying to run this on a machine with a local spark install. I think that my application doesnt know where spark is this is. How do I change this so it can find spark and execute properly?

Comment: We are running spark unit test in local mode with mini hdfs cluster as junit rule.

Comment: The unit test calls the main method directly....

Comment: @Alexander.Furer, I copied nd pasted the contents of main into the test.

How do you setup what you described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied and pasted the contents of my main into a JUnit class. I then created a TestRunner clas whick kicks off the JUnit.

To execute I use the same command as above but pass `--class com.ic.spark.sto.test.TestRunner` instead of `--class com.ic.spark.sto.test.Runner`

The `core-site.xml` file was in the wrong location.